# Fast scroll with cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport shown empty spaces, any solution with Angular15+?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular15, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

Fast scroll with cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport shown empty spaces, any solution with Angular15+ ?